# tkinter - Infinite Canvas "world" / "view" - keeping track of items in view

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tk-toolkit

I feel like this is a little bit complicated or at least I'm confused on it, so I'll try to explain it by rendering the issue. Let me know if the issue isn't clear.

---

I get the output from my `viewing_box` through the `__init__` method and it shows:
`(0, 0, 378, 265)`
Which is equivalent to a width of 378 and a height of 265.

When failing, I track the output:

```
1 false
1 false
here ([0.0, -60.0], [100.0, 40.0]) (0, 60, 378, 325)
```

The tracking is done in `_scan_view` with the code:

```
            if not viewable:
                current = self.itemcget(item,'tags')
                if isinstance(current, tuple):
                    new = current-('viewable',)
                else:
                    print('here',points, (x1,y1,x2,y2))
                    new = ''
                    self.inview_items.discard(item)
```

So the rectangle stays with width and height of 100, the coords however failing to be the expected ones. While view width and height stays the same and moves correctly in my current understanding. Expected:
`if x1 <= point[0] <= x2 and y1 <= point[1] <= y2:` and it feels like I've created two coordinate systems but I don't get it. Is someone looking on it and see it immediately?

Full Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class InfiniteCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.inview_items   = set()  #in view
        self.niview_items   = set()  #not in view
        self._xshifted      = 0     #view moved in x direction
        self._yshifted      = 0     #view moved in y direction
        self._multi         = 0
        self.configure(confine=False,highlightthickness=0,bd=0)
        self.bind('<MouseWheel>',       self._vscroll)
        self.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', self._hscroll)
        root.bind('<Control-KeyPress>',lambda e:setattr(self,'_multi', 10))
        root.bind('<Control-KeyRelease>',lambda e:setattr(self,'_multi', 0))
        print(self.viewing_box())
        return None

    def viewing_box(self):
        'returns x1,y1,x2,y2 of the currently visible area'
        x1 = 0 - self._xshifted
        y1 = 0 - self._yshifted
        x2 = self.winfo_reqwidth()-self._xshifted
        y2 = self.winfo_reqheight()-self._yshifted
        return x1,y1,x2,y2

    def _scan_view(self):
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = self.viewing_box()
        for item in self.find_withtag('viewable'):
            #check if one felt over the edge
            coords = self.coords(item)
            #https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-tuple-into-groups-of-n/
            points = tuple(
                coords[x:x + 2] for x in range(0, len(coords), 2))
            viewable = False
            for point in points:
                if x1 <= point[0] <= x2 and y1 <= point[1] <= y2:
                    #if any point is in viewing box
                    viewable = True
                    print(item, 'true')
                else:
                    print(item, 'false' )
            if not viewable:
                current = self.itemcget(item,'tags')
                if isinstance(current, tuple):
                    new = current-('viewable',)
                else:
                    print('here',points, (x1,y1,x2,y2))
                    new = ''
                    self.inview_items.discard(item)
                self.itemconfigure(item,tags=new)
        for item in self.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2):
            #check if item inside of viewing_box not in inview_items
            if item not in self.inview_items:
                self.inview_items.add(item)
                current = self.itemcget(item,'tags')
                if isinstance(current, tuple):
                    new = current+('viewable',)
                elif isinstance(current, str):
                    if str:
                        new = (current, 'viewable')
                    else:
                        new = 'viewable'
                    self.itemconfigure(item,tags=new)
        print(self.inview_items)

    def _create(self, *args):
        if (current:=args[-1].get('tags', False)):
            args[-1]['tags'] = current+('viewable',)
        else:
            args[-1]['tags'] = ('viewable',)
        ident = super()._create(*args)
        self._scan_view()
        return ident

    def _hscroll(self,event):
        offset = int(event.delta/120)
        if self._multi:
            offset = int(offset*self._multi)
        canvas.move('all', offset,0)
        self._xshifted += offset
        self._scan_view()

    def _vscroll(self,event):
        offset = int(event.delta/120)
        if self._multi:
            offset = int(offset*self._multi)
        canvas.move('all', 0,offset)
        self._yshifted += offset
        self._scan_view()

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = InfiniteCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

size, offset, start = 100, 10, 0
canvas.create_rectangle(start,start, size,size, fill='green')
canvas.create_rectangle(
    start+offset,start+offset, size+offset,size+offset, fill='darkgreen')

root.mainloop()
```

---

PS: Before thinking this is over-complicated and using just `find_overlapping` isn't working, since it seems the item needs to be at least `51%` in the view to get tracked with tkinters algorithm.

### [You can find an improved version now on CodeReview!](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283227/228833)

Comment: I don't understand what we're supposed to do when we run this code. What are you doing to  trigger the bad behavior? Also, what is the purpose of `_scan_view`? What is it designed to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley it's a different implementation of scrolling. Instead of the `View` I reposition the items in the `View` and I think I have ended up with two coordinate systems by doing that and unable to find the error in my method.

Comment: Are you aware of the `canvasx` and `canvasy` methods which can convert coordinates on a scrolled canvas to coordinates in the viewable area? I suspect that those methods might be part of the solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am aware of them, but not sure how to use them or how they could be related at the moment. Feels like a knot in my head ^^

Comment: You still haven't explained what we're supposed to do. There aren't any scrollbars to interact with. Are we supposed to scroll with the wheel? What triggers the bad behavior?

Comment: Yes using the `MouseWheel` will move the items in a direction and I want to know what items are `viewable` at the time and store them in `self.inview_items`. The `set()` doesn't match what I see on my window.

Comment: @BryanOakley found something that works, but if you know a better approach without the whole fuss I coded, I would be open for a simpler solution.

Comment: I don't know if this solves it for you but the messages at least seems to be correct after these changes. When you use `coords` the coordinates seems to be based on the frame not the viewport, if you change the comparison to `0 <= point[0] <= x2 - x1 and 0 <= point[1] <= y2 - y1` and `self.find_overlapping(0,0,x2-x1,y2-y1)` it seems to work.

Comment: @PatrikGustavsson I'll test it tomorrow. But now that you mention it, it should explain why my code fails. Cause the viewable rect stays the same and items move, seems logical to me now. So I basically shouldn't have tracked the viewable rect, which seems to be an artefact of a previous attempt. If that's the case, you can state it as answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley if you interested in it, the final code is now on CodeReview https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283227/228833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't know what I have done wrong but it works with `scan_dragto`.

```
import tkinter as tk

class InfiniteCanvas(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.inview_items   = set()  #in view
        self.niview_items   = set()  #not in view
        self._xshifted      = 0     #view moved in x direction
        self._yshifted      = 0     #view moved in y direction
        self._multi         = 0
        self.configure(confine=False,highlightthickness=0,bd=0)
        self.bind('<MouseWheel>',       self._vscroll)
        self.bind('<Shift-MouseWheel>', self._hscroll)
        root.bind('<Control-KeyPress>',lambda e:setattr(self,'_multi', 10))
        root.bind('<Control-KeyRelease>',lambda e:setattr(self,'_multi', 0))
        return None

    def viewing_box(self):
        'returns x1,y1,x2,y2 of the currently visible area'
        x1 = 0 - self._xshifted
        y1 = 0 - self._yshifted
        x2 = self.winfo_reqwidth()-self._xshifted
        y2 = self.winfo_reqheight()-self._yshifted
        return x1,y1,x2,y2

    def _scan_view(self):
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = self.viewing_box()
        for item in self.find_withtag('viewable'):
            #check if one felt over the edge
            coords = self.coords(item)
            #https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-tuple-into-groups-of-n/
            points = tuple(
                coords[x:x + 2] for x in range(0, len(coords), 2))
            viewable = False
            for point in points:
                if x1 <= point[0] <= x2 and y1 <= point[1] <= y2:
                    #if any point is in viewing box
                    viewable = True
            if not viewable:
                current = self.itemcget(item,'tags')
                if isinstance(current, tuple):
                    new = current-('viewable',)
                else:
                    print('here',points, (x1,y1,x2,y2))
                    new = ''
                    self.inview_items.discard(item)
                self.itemconfigure(item,tags=new)
        for item in self.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2):
            #check if item inside of viewing_box not in inview_items
            if item not in self.inview_items:
                self.inview_items.add(item)
                current = self.itemcget(item,'tags')
                if isinstance(current, tuple):
                    new = current+('viewable',)
                elif isinstance(current, str):
                    if str:
                        new = (current, 'viewable')
                    else:
                        new = 'viewable'
                    self.itemconfigure(item,tags=new)
        print(self.inview_items)

    def _create(self, *args):
        if (current:=args[-1].get('tags', False)):
            args[-1]['tags'] = current+('viewable',)
        else:
            args[-1]['tags'] = ('viewable',)
        ident = super()._create(*args)
        self._scan_view()
        return ident

    def _hscroll(self,event):
        offset = int(event.delta/120)
        if self._multi:
            offset = int(offset*self._multi)
        cx,cy = self.winfo_rootx(), self.winfo_rooty()
        self.scan_mark(cx, cy)
        self.scan_dragto(cx+offset, cy, gain=1)
        self._xshifted += offset
        self._scan_view()

    def _vscroll(self,event):
        offset = int(event.delta/120)
        if self._multi:
            offset = int(offset*self._multi)
        cx,cy = self.winfo_rootx(), self.winfo_rooty()
        self.scan_mark(cx, cy)
        self.scan_dragto(cx, cy+offset, gain=1)
        self._yshifted += offset
        self._scan_view()

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = InfiniteCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

size, offset, start = 100, 10, 0
canvas.create_rectangle(start,start, size,size, fill='green')
canvas.create_rectangle(
    start+offset,start+offset, size+offset,size+offset, fill='darkgreen')

root.mainloop()
```